# Python: re-defining a class method at runtime

Tags: python

I've defined a class like this:

```
class MyClass:
  def GetValue(self):
    return 5
  def PrintValue(self):
    print self.GetValue()
```

For some instances of MyClass I need to re-define the GetValue() dinamically, i.e. something like this:

```
def GetAGoodValue(self):
  return 7

oneObject=MyClass()
oneObject.GetValue=GetAGoodValue
oneObject.PrintValue()
```

After re-defining I get the errror:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments; expected 1, got 0
```

If inside the PrintValue method I code instead:

```
print self.GetValue(self)
```

then the above code works, but only for those MyClass instances where the GetValue method is re-defined. Instances where the GetValue method is not re-defined yeld the error:

```
TypeError: too many arguments; expected 1, got 2
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It's more a duplicate of the older http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object , which has a nicer answer as well.

Comment: Exactly. The originally linked question is about changing methods of a class, not of an object, which is a slightly different topic.

Comment: @Evert Must be one of the first ones here... #972, wow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a method to a single object instead of changing the whole class, you have to implement the ususally-done binding yourself.

So you have two options:

Either you do

```
oneObject.GetValue = lambda: GetAGoodValue(oneObject)
```

or you "ask" the function object what it would do if called as a class attribute:

```
oneObject.GetValue = GetAGoodValue.__get__(oneObject, MyClass)
```

so that it works as intended.

Comment: Sorry for being back so late, not enough time! Thank you for your answer. Your first suggestion works. The second gives me the following error:

`AttributeError: __get__`

Maybe it's because I'm working with a very old version of Python (1.5.2): unfortunately I have to!

Comment: @user1737538 Yes, the descriptor protocol (the thing with `__get__`) is newer than 1.5.2...

Comment: One more question: I'm trying to use your suggestion to implement another "function substitution". This time the function has some parameters, something like `GetScaledValue(self,min,max)`. What I'm trying to do is to assign `oneObject.GetScaledValue=lambda: GetAGoodScaledValue(oneObject,min,max)' but I get the error 'TypeError: no arguments expected' when I call `self.GetScaledValue(10,100)` from inside the class. Sorry, but I'm very new to this language (used to .NET).

Comment: I got it: it must be `oneObject.GetScaledValue=lambda min,max: GetAGoodScaledValue(oneObject,min,max)`.